# How to filter view with date field by today's date?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I came up short on good ways to filter a user list to only show users who's birthday is today.

There has been [efforts in D6](http://drupal.org/node/313498) but nothing in D7?

As a "hack" I used an exposed filter for the birthday field (a [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field) and then created a link from a block using PHP code:

```
$today = date("m-d", strtotime("today"));
print '<a href=/members/birthday?birthday='.$today.'>Today\'s Birthdays</a>';
```

Ideally, I would like to override the input field with a select option to show " yesterday, today, tomorrow, next week".

Are there any better options doing this in D7?

Comment: Doesn't a regular date filter already support doing a check for field_birthday == now with granularity? I guess not by the long issue you linked to, but right away, I don't see the problem?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I can do that with the "user created" date field. Not sure what went wrong, I select the "date" type and the field list shows that it's "Date (module: Date)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems like you already have an answer, so I'm posting it as such.

A regular date filter already has support for doing a check for field_birthday == now. You can granularity, such as hour, day, week, and even do simple arithmatic, "now + 1 day" and similar.

Comment: turns out that I didn't have the "date views" module installed. Once I did that I could select a date and it now shows a date widget as exposed filter.